# Why does my MFC dll not register if Platform is set to V110?

Tags: c++, dll, crt

I've been working on a project for a little over a year now. Since I started the project it was first worked on in VS2008. Use of MFC was set to Shared Library. I got the project and since I didn't have VS2008 I upgraded the project to V100. When I released the driver to the customer they got back with me and said that the new library didn't work until they installed C++ runtime 2010. I was baffled at first, but then figured it was because MFC was set to Shared. I told them that this was required and they were ok with that. I never understood the reason behind it, but just went with it. Well fast forward a few months and VS2012 came out and I jumped on that band wagon. It displays C++ code (in my opinion) much better. Now at some point I was playing with the settings and changed the character set to Unicode (from none) and MFC in a static library. This caused the DLL to increase in size a bit which I thought would solve the problem of needing VC100crt installed. So when I upgraded I also upgraded the platform tool set to V110. Built it and wanted the person to test it out on their system before I released it. He shot back saying it wouldn't register, and his program didn't recognize it. So i recompiled using V100 and it worked for him.

So what am I missing? Why does it require that V100crt to be installed to register my dll. Another similar library is also loaded (not sure what the compile options are) but it doesn't appear to need any CRT's installed... thoughts?

**EDIT**

**C++ Compile Options**

```
/Yu"StdAfx.h"
/GS
/analyze-
/W3
/Zc:wchar_t
/Zi
/Gm-
/Od
/Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb"
/fp:precise
/D "WIN32"
/D "_WINDOWS"
/D "_DEBUG"
/D "_USRDLL"
/D "_WINDLL"
/D "_UNICODE"
/D "UNICODE"
/errorReport:prompt
/WX-
/Zc:forScope
/Gd
/Oy-
/MTd
/Fa"Debug\"
/EHsc
/nologo
/Fo"Debug\"
/Fp"Debug\MyLibrary.pch"
```

wow that is a long auto-generated list :/ ugh.. here is the linker. Wish I understood these better.

**Linker Options**

```
/OUT:"C:\Subversion\MyLibrary\Debug\MyLibrary.dll"
/MANIFEST
/NXCOMPAT
/PDB:"C:\Subversion\MyLibrary\Debug\MyLibrary.pdb"
/DYNAMICBASE
/ALLOWISOLATION
/DEF:".\MyLibrary.def"
/DEBUG
/DLL
/MACHINE:X86
/INCREMENTAL
/PGD:"C:\Subversion\MyLibrary\Debug\MyLibrary.pgd"
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker'
uiAccess='false'"
/ManifestFile:"Debug\MyLibrary.dll.intermediate.manifest"
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT
/NOLOGO
/TLBID:1
```

**Config options**
General:

```
Target Extension: .dll
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2012 (v110)
```

Project Defaults:

```
Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
Use of MFC: Use MFC in a Static Library
Use of ATL: Not using ATL
Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set
Common Language Runtime Support: No Common Language Runtime Support
Whole Program Optimization: No Whole Program Optimization
Windows Store App Support: No
```

I had also found somewhere to not embed my manifest . So i changed that to No.

Comment: It is the exact same problem you ignored before.  Just changing the MFC setting isn't enough, the C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime library setting matters as well.  Only use /MT if you don't have any DLLs.  Asking the user to download and run the VS2012 vcredist installer solves it again.  Do test this on a clean machine or VM before you let the client shoot his foot :)

Comment: @HansPassant what does that mean `Only use /MT if you don't have any DLLs` there are 2 included C style libraries used by my DLL. I'll edit my post and put up my build options

Comment: You are not *really* shipping the Debug build are you?  And of course you'd have to show the v110 toolset build options, not the ones you don't have a problem with.

Comment: @HansPassant No I'm not shipping the Debug version to them. I have a tester with them that we use the Debug version. When he gives the thumbs up I change the build to Release and he tests it again (just not as much) and then we release it. Also i edited my post to show the config options